# Using session to reach previous page after login in laravel

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-authorization

I am using Laravel 5.7. For security reasons, I set my laravel application to automatically logout after one hour inactivity. But I want the user log back in the same page before they got kicked out by the system. I try to use Session, but it only store previous url which is the login page url. How can I retrieve that URL before user got automatically logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is put this in your logout function.

```
session(['returnUrl' => url()->previous()]);
```

And then on login function, redirect user to `session('returnUrl')` and delete session data with `session()->forget('returnUrl')`

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your login controller

```
url()->previous()
```